# Move div with arrow key in jQuery 1.6.1 does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-1.6

In JQuery 1.6.1, we can supposedly use `+=` or `-=` with `css()` just as we can do with `animate()`, but this isn't working. Does anyone see a problem with the code?

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {  
    if (e.which == 37) { //37 left arrow key.
        $('div').css('left', '-=10px')
    }
});
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/QLFEy/3

Comment: Moderator note: Comments under this question have been removed due to community flags on comments that would quickly result in a disjointed and confusing conversation once automatically deleted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code is correct and should work. Looking at jQuery bug tracker, i found an already open ticket for this at http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9237. It works with width and height but not with left at least. According to the ticket, fix should be available in 1.6.2

**Update 05/13/11**

The issue has been **fixed** and the fix is currently available in the WIP version which can be found at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js. This is the very latest non production version of jQuery with most recent fixes. The fix should be be officially available in the upcoming  1.6.2 version.

Comment: The bug references hyphenated properties.  `left` isn't hyphenated.

Comment: @Rocket Please familiarize yourself with jQuery changlog before posting. According to jQuery 1.6 change log, we can use left, http://blog.jquery.com/.

Comment: @Pinkie: Please familiarize yourself with this question (you asked it).  According to the jsFiddle you posted, we can't use left, seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously a bug in jQuery.  It seems like jQuery is not adding "px" after the value.

```
[2011-05-12 21:46:17] CSS - file://localhost/D:/test.html
DOM style property
Invalid value for property: margin-left
Line 1:
  260
  ---^
```

Comment: heh? where did `margin-left` come from?

Comment: i've tested various css properties. it's strange thats working for height, width but not for padding, margin, left, etc...