# Incremental CSS positioning not working

Tags: jquery, css

I swear this should work, but it's not. I must be missing something simple:

HTML:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#box {
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#box').click(function(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey)
        $(this).css('left', '70px');
    else
        $(this).css('left', '+=50');
});
```

---

If you shift+click, the box moves as it should. Try clicking without shift, and the box does not increase its left edge position by 50px. What gives?

Comment: It's a jQuery bug, which I'm struggling to find a link to. It's been asked here quite a few times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move div with arrow key in jQuery 1.6.1 does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983034/move-div-with-arrow-key-in-jquery-1-6-1-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9237

The bug will be fixed in `1.6.2`.

Broken: http://jsfiddle.net/Kwpuq/

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/Kwpuq/1/ - that's using "jQuery (edge)"

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Argh, they fixed $.css() but not $.animate().

Comment: If you need it work now, stick with `parseInt($(this).css('left')) + 50 + "px"`.

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack: You don't need the `+ "px"` on the end. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#_testList').css('left', (parseFloat($('#_testList').css('left')) + 10) + 'px');
```

This gets the numeric part of the string - in this case it gets the 10 out of 10px - adds 10, then appends 'px'. In css, you must have the unit of measurement at the end of the value.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I solution could be the following:

```
$('#box').click(function(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey)
        $(this).css('left', '70px');
    else {
       var left = parseInt($(this).css('left'));
        left+=50;
        $(this).css('left',left)}
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/JYAqr/

`$(this).css('left')` return a string so you must prase it as integer and then add 50px

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$(this).css('left', '+=50');
```

to:

```
$(this).css('left', '+=50px');
```

Comment: Of course I tried that. jQuery documentation shows that you do not use 'px' when using += or -=